# ProxyPass not working on Ubuntu 14

Tags: apache2.4

While I have no problem with Ubuntu 12.04, in a fresh 14.04 installation I cannot proxy my app in Tomcat from port 8080 to 80. I added in the apache.conf the following:

```
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

But I get the error:

```
[proxy:error] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[proxy:error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s
[proxy_http:error] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

I tried several configurations but the connection always timed out.

Comment: This is not a problem with apache, but with tomcat running on port:8080. Check 127.0.0.1:8080 is accessible from localhost. What is `netstat -tlpn` ouput?

Comment: @7171u Tomcat and my app respond on port 8080. The netstat output is:               tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: `netstat` output indicates that tomcat is listening on port `8080` only over IPv6?  You should change conf files in tomcat to listen port `8080` over IPv4 from `localhost`

Comment: @7171u I've change both tomcat7 and apache so netstat output is now:      tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -  but my app still timeouts on port 80 (still working on 8080)

Comment: This is OK. Check if selinux is enabled with `getenforce`. if enabled disable with `setenforce 0` and try again.

Comment: SELinux status: disabled but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you restart apache after this? If this doesnt work do  `/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1` and restart apache.

Comment: I did, also restarted the server

Comment: setsebool: SELinux is disabled. But still  HTTP: failed to make connection to backend

Comment: Solved... there was a mistake in my iptables. The loopback port was blocked.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was related to `iptables` that was blocking the loopback port. I needed to add :

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```